# PostgreSQL INNER JOIN vs WHERE clause join

Tags: postgresql, join, inner-join

I thought INNER JOIN was equivalent to JOIN in WHERE clause. When I make join using WHERE clause, I get rows returned. But if I do INNER JOIN, then no rows are outputed. I get result that there are no matches.
 Am I mistaken, or I'm doing something wrong?

Are these joins equivalent?:

INNNER JOIN:

```
account_move_reconcile_line_applied amrla
INNER JOIN account_move_reconcile_line amrl ON (amrla.credit_line_id = amrl.id)
INNER JOIN account_move_reconcile amr ON (amrl.credit_reconcile_id = amr.id)
INNER JOIN account_move_line aml ON (aml.reconcile_partial_id = amr.id)
INNER JOIN res_partner rp ON (aml.partner_id = rp.id)
```

IN WHERE clause:

```
amrla.credit_line_id = amrl.id
and amrl.partner_id = rp.id
and amrl.credit_reconcile_id = amr.id
and aml.reconcile_id = amr.id
```

Comment: Check the query plans, they will probably be the same.

Comment: Sorry about the question.. I didn't saw that in INNER JOIN I used different ID..

Comment: `and aml.reconcile_id = amr.id` vs. `aml.reconcile_partial_id = amr.id` aren't the same, and `aml.partner_id = rp.id` and `amrl.partner_id = rp.id` aren't either. Are they supposed to match?

Comment: Sorry again, I said in comments that I miss looked. Everything is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was wrong ID in:

```
INNER JOIN account_move_line aml ON (aml.reconcile_partial_id = amr.id)
```

It should have been reconcile_id instead of reconcile_partial_id.

Comment: Thanks for following up. Sometimes it can be easier to spot this sort of thing by looking at the `explain` plans, by the way.